# Multiple choice quiz for maths and history, with saved score reports

Tags: python, python-3.x, quiz

This is a program I have been working on in python. It is meant to be a quiz to some secondary school pupils on two subjects/topics which are maths and history.

So far, it allows a user to try the quiz on one of the subjects and gives them a grade, percentage and score according to what they have answered correctly in the quiz. However, the program seems long-winded with two very big functions as well:

```
print("Welcome to my quiz!")
def maths():
    with open("maths.txt","r") as topic1:
        score = 0
        difficultyLevel = input("Please select a difficulty level for the  maths quiz:easy, medium or hard:")
        questionsForMaths = topic1.readlines() 
        print("The maths questions:")
        if difficultyLevel == "Easy" or difficultyLevel == "easy": 
            for x in range(0,3):
                print(questionsForMaths[x].rstrip()) 
            userAnswer = input("Choose from the following:").lower()
            if userAnswer == questionsForMaths[1].rstrip():
                print ("correct")
                score = score + 1 
            else:
                print ("incorrect")
            #2nd question 
            for x in range(5,8):
                print(questionsForMaths[x].rstrip()) 
            userAnswer = input("Choose from the following:").lower()
            if userAnswer == questionsForMaths[7].rstrip():
                print ("correct")
                score = score + 1 
            else:
                print ("incorrect")
            #3rd question
            for x in range(10,13):
                print(questionsForMaths[x].rstrip())
            userAnswer = input("Choose from the following:").lower()
            if userAnswer == questionsForMaths[12].rstrip():
                print ("correct")
                score = score + 1 
            else:
                print ("incorrect")
            #4th question
            for x in range(15,18):
                print(questionsForMaths[x].rstrip())
            userAnswer = input("Choose from the following:").lower() 
            if userAnswer == questionsForMaths[16].rstrip():
                print("correct")
                score = score + 1
            else:
                print("incorrect")
            #5th question
            for x in range(20,23):
                print(questionsForMaths[x].rstrip())
            userAnswer = input("Choose from the following:")
            if userAnswer == questionsForMaths[22].rstrip():
                print("correct")
                score = score + 1
            else:
                print("incorrect")
        elif difficultyLevel == "Medium" or difficultyLevel == "medium": 
            for x in range(0,4):
                print(questionsForMaths[x].rstrip()) 
            userAnswer = input("Choose from the following:").lower()
            if userAnswer == questionsForMaths[1].rstrip():
                print ("correct")
                score = score + 1 
            else:
                print ("incorrect")
            #2nd question 
            for x in range(5,9):
                print(questionsForMaths[x].rstrip()) 
            userAnswer = input("Choose from the following:").lower()
            if userAnswer == questionsForMaths[7].rstrip():
                print ("correct")
                score = score + 1 
            else:
                print ("incorrect")
            #3rd question
            for x in range(10,14):
                print(questionsForMaths[x].rstrip())
            userAnswer = input("Choose from the following:").lower()
            if userAnswer == questionsForMaths[12].rstrip():
                print ("correct")
                score = score + 1 
            else:
                print ("incorrect")
            #4th question
            for x in range(15,19):
                print(questionsForMaths[x].rstrip())
            userAnswer = input("Choose from the following:").lower() 
            if userAnswer == questionsForMaths[16].rstrip():
                print("correct")
                score = score + 1
            else:
                print("incorrect")
            #5th question
            for x in range(20,24):
                print(questionsForMaths[x].rstrip())
            userAnswer = input("Choose from the following:")
            if userAnswer == questionsForMaths[22].rstrip():
                print("correct")
                score = score + 1
            else:
                print("incorrect")

        elif difficultyLevel == "Hard" or difficultyLevel == "hard":
            for x in range(0,5):
                print(questionsForMaths[x].rstrip()) 
            userAnswer = input("Choose from the following:").lower()
            if userAnswer == questionsForMaths[1].rstrip():
                print ("correct")
                score = score + 1 
            else:
                print ("incorrect")
            #2nd question 
            for x in range(5,10):
                print(questionsForMaths[x].rstrip()) 
            userAnswer = input("Choose from the following:").lower()
            if userAnswer == questionsForMaths[7].rstrip():
                print ("correct")
                score = score + 1 
            else:
                print ("incorrect")
            #3rd question
            for x in range(10,15):
                print(questionsForMaths[x].rstrip())
            userAnswer = input("Choose from the following:").lower()
            if userAnswer == questionsForMaths[12].rstrip():
                print ("correct")
                score = score + 1 
            else:
                print ("incorrect")
            #4th question
            for x in range(15,20):
                print(questionsForMaths[x].rstrip())
            userAnswer = input("Choose from the following:").lower() 
            if userAnswer == questionsForMaths[16].rstrip():
                print("correct")
                score = score + 1
            else:
                print("incorrect")
            #5th question
            for x in range(20,25):
                print(questionsForMaths[x].rstrip())
            userAnswer = input("Choose from the following:")
            if userAnswer == questionsForMaths[22].rstrip():
                print("correct")
                score = score + 1
            else:
                print("incorrect")
        print("Your total score is", score)
        percentage = (score/5)*100
        print("The percentage of questions correct is", percentage)
        if percentage < 40.0:
            print("You have failed the maths quiz")
            with open("reports.txt","a") as reports:
                reports.write("\n" + fullUsername + " " + "achieved a grade of fail" + " " + "in the maths quiz") 
        elif percentage >= 40.0 and percentage <= 60.0:
            print("You have passed the maths quiz")
            with open("reports.txt","a") as reports:
                reports.write("\n" + fullUsername + " " + "achieved a grade of pass" + " " + "in the maths quiz")
        elif percentage >= 60.0 and percentage <= 80.0:
            print("You have achieved merit for the maths quiz")
            with open("reports.txt","a") as reports:
                reports.write("\n" + fullUsername + " " + "achieved a grade of merit" + " " + "in the maths quiz")
        elif percentage > 80.0:
            print("You have achieved distinction for maths quiz")
            with open("reports.txt","a") as reports:
                reports.write("\n" + fullUsername + " " + "achieved a grade of distinction" + " " + "in the maths quiz")
        with open("reports.txt","a") as reports:
           reports.write("\n" + fullUsername + " " + "did the maths quiz and" + " " + "achieved a score of" + " " + str(score))
           reports.write("\n" + fullUsername + " " + "did the maths quiz and" + " " + "achieved a percentage of" + " " + str(percentage))


def history(): 
    with open("history.txt","r") as topic2:
         score = 0 
         print("The history questions:") 
         difficultyLevel = input("Please select a difficulty level for the  history quiz:easy, medium or hard:")
         questionsForHistory = topic2.readlines()
         if difficultyLevel == "Easy" or difficultyLevel == "easy":
            for y in range(0,3):
                print(questionsForHistory[y].rstrip()) 
            userAnswer2 = input("Choose from the following:")
            if userAnswer2 == questionsForHistory[2].rstrip():
                print("correct")
                score = score + 1
            else:
                print("incorrect")
            #2nd question 
            for y in range(5,8):
                print(questionsForHistory[y].rstrip()) 
            userAnswer2 = input("Choose from the following:")
            if userAnswer2 == questionsForHistory[6].rstrip():
                print("correct")
                score = score + 1
            else:
                print("incorrect")
            #3rd question
            for y in range(10,13):
                print(questionsForHistory[y].rstrip()) 
            userAnswer2 = input("Choose from the following:")
            if userAnswer2 == questionsForHistory[12].rstrip() or userAnswer2 == questionsForHistory[12].rstrip().lower():
                print("correct")
                score = score + 1
            else:
                print("incorrect")
            #4th question
            for y in range(15,18):
                print(questionsForHistory[y].rstrip()) 
            userAnswer2 = input("Choose from the following:")
            if userAnswer2 == questionsForHistory[17].rstrip():
                print("correct")
                score = score + 1
            else:
                print("incorrect")
            #5th question
            for y in range(20,23):
                print(questionsForHistory[y].rstrip()) 
            userAnswer2 = input("Choose from the following:")
            if userAnswer2 == questionsForHistory[21].rstrip():
                print("correct")
                score = score + 1
            else:
                print("incorrect")
         elif difficultyLevel == "Medium" or difficultyLevel == "medium":
            for y in range(0,4):
                print(questionsForHistory[y].rstrip()) 
            userAnswer2 = input("Choose from the following:")
            if userAnswer2 == questionsForHistory[2].rstrip():
                print("correct")
                score = score + 1
            else:
                print("incorrect")
            #2nd question 
            for y in range(5,9):
                print(questionsForHistory[y].rstrip()) 
            userAnswer2 = input("Choose from the following:")
            if userAnswer2 == questionsForHistory[6].rstrip():
                print("correct")
                score = score + 1
            else:
                print("incorrect")
            #3rd question
            for y in range(10,14):
                print(questionsForHistory[y].rstrip()) 
            userAnswer2 = input("Choose from the following:")
            if userAnswer2 == questionsForHistory[12].rstrip() or userAnswer2 == questionsForHistory[12].rstrip().lower():
                print("correct")
                score = score + 1
            else:
                print("incorrect")
            #4th question 
            for y in range(15,19):
                print(questionsForHistory[y].rstrip()) 
            userAnswer2 = input("Choose from the following:")
            if userAnswer2 == questionsForHistory[17].rstrip():
                print("correct")
                score = score + 1
            else:
                print("incorrect")
            #5th question
            for y in range(20,24):
                print(questionsForHistory[y].rstrip()) 
            userAnswer2 = input("Choose from the following:")
            if userAnswer2 == questionsForHistory[21].rstrip():
                print("correct")
                score = score + 1
            else:
                print("incorrect")
         elif difficultyLevel == "Hard" or difficultyLevel == "hard":
            for y in range(0,5):
                print(questionsForHistory[y].rstrip()) 
            userAnswer2 = input("Choose from the following:")
            if userAnswer2 == questionsForHistory[2].rstrip():
                print("correct")
                score = score + 1
            else:
                print("incorrect")
            #2th question 
            for y in range(5,10):
                print(questionsForHistory[y].rstrip()) 
            userAnswer2 = input("Choose from the following:")
            if userAnswer2 == questionsForHistory[6].rstrip():
                print("correct")
                score = score + 1
            else:
                print("incorrect")
            #3rd question
            for y in range(10,15):
                print(questionsForHistory[y].rstrip()) 
            userAnswer2 = input("Choose from the following:")
            if userAnswer2 == questionsForHistory[12].rstrip() or userAnswer2 == questionsForHistory[12].rstrip().lower():
                print("correct")
                score = score + 1
            else:
                print("incorrect")
            #4th question
            for y in range(15,20):
                print(questionsForHistory[y].rstrip()) 
            userAnswer2 = input("Choose from the following:")
            if userAnswer2 == questionsForHistory[17].rstrip():
                print("correct")
                score = score + 1
            else:
                print("incorrect")
            #5th question
            for y in range(20,25):
                print(questionsForHistory[y].rstrip()) 
            userAnswer2 = input("Choose from the following:")
            if userAnswer2 == questionsForHistory[21].rstrip():
                print("correct")
                score = score + 1
            else:
                print("incorrect")
    print("Your total score is", score)
    percentage = (score/5)*100
    print("The percentage of questions correct is", percentage) 
    if percentage < 40.0:
        print("You have failed the history quiz")
        with open("reports.txt","a") as reports:
                reports.write("\n" + fullUsername + " " + "achieved a grade of fail" + " " + "in the history quiz") 
    elif percentage >= 40.0 and percentage <= 60.0:
        print("You have passed the history quiz")
        with open("reports.txt","a") as reports:
                reports.write("\n" + fullUsername + " " + "achieved a grade of pass" + " " + "in the history quiz")
    elif percentage >= 60.0 and percentage <= 80.0:
        print("You have achieved merit for the history quiz")
        with open("reports.txt","a") as reports:
                reports.write("\n" + fullUsername + " " + "achieved a grade of merit" + " " + "in the history quiz")
    elif percentage > 80.0:
        print("You have achieved distinction for history quiz")
        with open("reports.txt","a") as reports:
                reports.write("\n" + fullUsername + " " + "achieved a grade of distinction" + " " + "in the history quiz")
    with open("reports.txt","a") as reports:
           reports.write("\n" + fullUsername + " " + "did the history quiz and" + " " + "achieved a score of" + " " + str(score))
           reports.write("\n" + fullUsername + " " + "did the history quiz and" + " " + "achieved a percentage of" + " " + str(percentage))


with open("user account .txt","w") as userFile:
    usernamePart1 = input("Enter your name:")
    while not usernamePart1.isalpha():
        print("Invalid name, try again")
        usernamePart1 = input("Enter your name:")
    usernamePart2 = input("Enter your age:")
    while not usernamePart2.isdigit():
        print("try again") 
        usernamePart2 = input("Enter your age:")
    fullUsername = usernamePart1[:3] + usernamePart2
    userFile.write("Username:" + fullUsername)
    with open("reports.txt","a") as reports:
        reports.write("\n" + "Username:" + fullUsername) 
    print(fullUsername)

    UserYearGroup = int(input("Enter your year group:"))
    while UserYearGroup < 7 or UserYearGroup > 11:
        print("Invalid year group, enter again")
        UserYearGroup = int(input("Enter your year group:"))
    if UserYearGroup >= 7 and UserYearGroup <= 11:
        userFile.write("\nYear Group:" + str(UserYearGroup))
        print(UserYearGroup)

    password = input("Enter your password, it must be at least 6 characters long and no more than 11 characters:")
    while len(password) < 6 or len(password) > 11:
        print("Invalid password, try again:")
        password = input("Enter your password, it must be at least 6 characters long and no more than 11 characters:")
    if len(password) >= 6 and len(password) <= 11:
       userFile.write("\nPassword:" + password)  




topicChoice = input("Which topic do you want to test yourself on : its either maths or history?")
his = "history".lower()
ma = "maths".lower()

if topicChoice == his:
    history()

elif topicChoice == ma:
    maths()
```

How can I make the program more efficient (i.e. fewer lines of code) and possibly not as repetitive?

Comment: Could you give us some idea what the first few lines of `maths.txt` look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lots repeated code, so we can define functions or parameters to be more efficient.

`maths` and `history` almost the same codes, so can just delete one and use `topic` as parameter

For questions part are the same. In different `difficultyLevel`, only the range for `x` and expected answer are different (and some little difference for the 3th question in `history` topic). All these can be more efficient.

Here is my code

```
user_account_filename = "user account .txt"
report_filename = "reports.txt"

expectedAnswers = {
    'maths':[1,7,12,16,22],
    'history':[2,6,12,17,21]
}

level2questions = {
    'easy':3,
    'medium':4,
    'hard':5
}

question_num = 5

def start_test(topic, fullUsername):

    score = 0
    questions_filename = topic + '.txt'
    questions = open(questions_filename).readlines() 
    difficultyLevel = input("Please select a difficulty level for the " + topic + " quiz:easy, medium or hard:")

    if difficultyLevel.lower() in ["easy","medium","hard"]:
        difficultyLevel = difficultyLevel.lower()
        print("The " + topic + " questions:")

        for i in range(question_num):
            for x in range(i * 5, i * 5 +\
            level2questions[difficultyLevel]):
                print(questions[x].rstrip()) 
            userAnswer = input("Choose from the following:").lower()

            if i == 2 and topic == "history":
                userAnswer2 = userAnswer2.lower()
            if userAnswer == questions[expectedAnswers[topic][i]].rstrip():
                print ("correct")
                score = score + 1 
            else:
                print ("incorrect")

    #TODO:else

    print("Your total score is", score)
    test_result(score, topic, fullUsername)


def test_result(score, topic, fullUsername):
    def test_result(result):
        report = "\n" + fullUsername + " achieved a grade of " + result + " in the " + topic + " quiz"
        if result in ["merit", "distinction"]:
            result = "achieved " + result + " for"
        else:
            result += "ed"
        printout = "You have " + result + " the " + topic + " quiz"
        return printout, report

    percentage = (score/5)*100
    print("The percentage of questions correct is", percentage)
    if percentage < 40.0:
        result = "fail"
    elif percentage >= 40.0 and percentage <= 60.0:
        result = "pass"
    elif percentage >= 60.0 and percentage <= 80.0:
        result = "merit"
    elif percentage > 80.0:
        result = "distinction"

    printout, report = test_result(result)
    print(printout)

    record_prefix = "\n" + fullUsername + " did the " + topic + " quiz and achieved a "
    write_file(report_filename, report + record_prefix + "score of " + str(score) + record_prefix + "percentage of " + str(percentage))



def write_file(path,data):
    with open(path,'a+') as f:
        f.write(data)

def main():
    print("Welcome to my quiz!")

    #fullUsername
    usernamePart1 = input("Enter your name:")
    while not usernamePart1.isalpha():
        print("Invalid name, try again")
        usernamePart1 = input("Enter your name:")
    usernamePart2 = input("Enter your age:")
    while not usernamePart2.isdigit():
        print("try again") 
        usernamePart2 = input("Enter your age:")
    fullUsername = usernamePart1[:3] + usernamePart2

    write_file(user_account_filename, "Username:" + fullUsername)
    write_file(report_filename, "\nUsername:" + fullUsername)

    print(fullUsername)

    #UserYearGroup
    #I have modified some code here, add `UserYearGroup.isdigit()` and delete the `if UserYearGroup >= 7 and UserYearGroup <= 11`
    UserYearGroup = input("Enter your year group:")
    while UserYearGroup.isdigit() and not (7 <= int(UserYearGroup) <= 11):
        print("Invalid year group, enter again")
        UserYearGroup = input("Enter your year group:")
    write_file(user_account_filename, "\nYear Group:" + UserYearGroup)
    print(UserYearGroup)


    #Password
    password = input("Enter your password, it must be at least 6 characters long and no more than 11 characters:")
    while not 6 <= len(password) <= 11:
        print("Invalid password, try again:")
        password = input("Enter your password, it must be at least 6 characters long and no more than 11 characters:")
    write_file(user_account_filename, "\nPassword:" + password)

    #TopicChoice
    topicChoice = input("Which topic do you want to test yourself on : its either maths or history?")
    #deleted `his` and `ma`
    if topicChoice.lower() in ["history","maths"]:
        start_test(topicChoice, fullUsername)
    #TODO:else 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Explainations**

1.`expectedAnswers` part:as you can see, in your original code, in maths/history topic, for different `difficultyLevel`,from question 1 to 5

```
if userAnswer == questionsForMaths[i].rstrip():
    print ("correct")
    score = score + 1 
else:
    print ("incorrect")
```

this part is repeated, except the `i` in `questionsForMaths[i]` (so I guess the `i` means "expected answer"). And also, in each `difficultLevel` the `i`s are all the same -- for maths topic from question 1 to 5, `i` equals 1,7,12,16 and 22; for history topic, `i` equals 2,6,12,17,21. Thus this is how `expectedAnswers` works

2.`level2questions` part: still in different `difficultyLevel`,from question 1 to 5

```
for x in range(i,j):
    print(questionsForMaths[x].rstrip())
```

this part is repeated, except the `i` and `j` in `for x in range(i,j)`.

Here is your original code

For easy difficulty level:

```
for x in range(0,3):
     print(questionsForMaths[x].rstrip()) 
...
#2nd question 
for x in range(5,8):
     print(questionsForMaths[x].rstrip())
...
#3rd question
for x in range(10,13):
     print(questionsForMaths[x].rstrip())
...
#4th question
for x in range(15,18):
     print(questionsForMaths[x].rstrip())
...
#5th question
for x in range(20,23):
     print(questionsForMaths[x].rstrip())
```

For medium difficulty level:

```
for x in range(0,4):
     print(questionsForMaths[x].rstrip()) 
...
#2nd question 
for x in range(5,9):
     print(questionsForMaths[x].rstrip())
...
#3rd question
for x in range(10,14):
     print(questionsForMaths[x].rstrip())
...
#4th question
for x in range(15,19):
     print(questionsForMaths[x].rstrip())
...
#5th question
for x in range(20,24):
     print(questionsForMaths[x].rstrip())
```

For hard difficulty level:

```
for x in range(0,5):
     print(questionsForMaths[x].rstrip()) 
...
#2nd question 
for x in range(5,10):
     print(questionsForMaths[x].rstrip())
...
#3rd question
for x in range(10,15):
     print(questionsForMaths[x].rstrip())
...
#4th question
for x in range(15,20):
     print(questionsForMaths[x].rstrip())
...
#5th question
for x in range(20,25):
     print(questionsForMaths[x].rstrip())
```

We can find something common in `x` rang here:

```
Difficult Level |  1st  |  2nd  |  3rd    |  4th    | 5th 

Easy            | (0,3) | (5,8) | (10,13) | (15,18) | (20,23)

Medium          | (0,4) | (5,9) | (10,14) | (15,19) | (20,24)

Hard            | (0,5) | (5,10)| (10,15) | (15,20) | (20,25)
```

So, all 1st question `x` all start from 0(equal (1-1) * 5), and 2nd start from 5(equal (2-1) * 5), and so on. So we can get `x` range start from 
(question_NO - 1) * 5, so this is the `i` part.

Then let's look at where does `x` range stop

For "easy" level, 1st question `x` end in 3(equal 0 + 3), 2nd question end in 8(equal 5 + 3), and so on. So `x` end in `i + 3`

Same thing for medium and hard level

"medium" level end in `i + 4`, "hard" level end in `i + 5`, this is the `j` part.

Now we have 3 magic numbers here -- 3 for easy level; 4 for medium level and 5 for hard level

So I use this `level2questions` to remove repeated code

```
level2questions = {
    'easy':3,
    'medium':4,
    'hard':5
}
```

We can get "the magic number" by target level -- `level2questions[level]`

So `x` end in `i + magic_number` that is `i + level2questions[level]` and replace the `i` we get before, we can rewrite the `for x in range(i,j)` to:

```
for x in range((question_NO - 1) * 5,\
(question_NO - 1) * 5 + level2questions[level]):
```

One more thing in my code:

```
for i in range(question_num):
      for x in range(i * 5, i * 5 +\
      level2questions[difficultyLevel]):
            print(questions[x].rstrip())
```

The `question_NO`(in my code it is `i`) start from 0, so just use `question_NO` replace `(question_NO - 1)`

3.last two line part: it means, if this code is executed as main programme (Or to say, when you run the python file from terminal), then run the `main()` function.

You can try it, create another python file and add `from [this python file name(without`.py`)] import *`, when you run the "another python file" on terminal, the `main()` function here won't work

Here are some better explaination for it

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do

and docs

[https://docs.python.org/3/library/**main**.html](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html)

### **Code Advice**

**First, find out common things, and try to define functions for them.** when you need one, just call the function.

In your code, lots repeated code in it. You can first remove those repeated code by define function.

If most code are similiar but only some "key points" are differnt, then you need add parameters in the function, key parameters are for those "key points"

An example:
`print("You have failed the maths quiz")` and `print("You have failed the history quiz")`
except the "math" and "history", all other are same here, so you can define such function

```
def failed_quiz(topic):
    print("You have failed the " + topic + " quiz")
```

I think this would be a good practice for you, so first, try to "kill" repeat code

**Then, find things common in logic.** this just as my `level2questions` part.

I think "create efficient programs" just like organize things in daily life, but we need more practice to get used in code life, anyway you have a good start, just keep coding and read other's code, your code will be better :)

Sorry can't give you resource link, as I don't know any, just keep practice^^

Comment: I tried to use your code above but the 'UserYearGroup' part is still a problem because the program stops running and gives a syntax error.

Comment: There are also other problems when the above code is ran for example write_file(user_account_filename, "\nYear Group:" + UserYearGroup)
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly.

Comment: @Z.Zayed I have modified the code, and should without problem in `UserYearGroup` part now.

Comment: can you explain to me what the expectedAnswers{} and level2questions{] part of the program does? Also what does the last two lines do in the program, I am not sure what is actually happening at that part either.

Comment: @Z.Zayed Sure, I will edit my answer with explainations

Comment: Thank you for your explanations but I still don't understand the concept of level2questions and the last two line part. Also, is it possible if you could give me some advice on how I can improve my programming skills in python because I just don't understand the more complex aspects of coding to create efficient programs like the one above.

Comment: If you can give me some links to helpful resources that would be great.

Comment: @Z.Zayed I have edited my answer, and if you still don't get it, I will keep try to explain^^ welcome any other questions

Comment: How would you find the average score from the quiz after a set of pupils did it and how could you find the highest score from the set of pupils who did the quiz if all of their scores where saved in an external text file?

Comment: @Z.Zayed `sum()` and  `max()` will help you

Comment: At point do I use those functions? I am not quite sure.

Comment: I am a student and I have limited knowledge of programming. Is it possible if you could change the program so that it is easier to understand especially those parts mentioned above. It is not a problem if the program is not as robust as I could fix that. This is because if the program is not as efficient but I can understand it fully is the main part.

Comment: ok, so the problem is you still can't understand my code, and want it be more easier right?

Comment: Is my explainations clear to you? sorry I am need sure my English expression is good enough for us to communicate

Answer (score 1):

The answer above is super long already. so I just start a new one.

## **Easier Version**

Usually while we write code, first list the steps then code.

> And keep in mind, **One function should do just one thing**

So let's analyse your structure first

*1.User input basic informations and save them in file*

*2.User choose topic to test*

*3.Start test*

**Input basic informations**

This part your code is great, just don't run it keep opening file.

So the structor here like

*1.read input information*

*2.save in file*

So here we can define two functions

```
def read_user_info():
    userInfo = input("Enter your information:")
    (some rules..)
    write_file(filename, content)


def write_file(filename, content):
    with open(filename,"a+") as f: 
        f.write(content)
```

Just like my `main()` and `write_file()` function above.

**User choose topic to test**

I wrote this part in `main()` too, as just one line, but better to write another function for it, might be more clear in structure.

**Start test**

Here is we need **Merge `maths()` and `history()`**

This two functions are similar

The structure of those two functions:

*1.open file*

```
#maths
with open("maths.txt","r") as topic1:
...
#history
with open("history.txt","r") as topic2:
...
```

*2.user choose difficulty level*

```
#maths
difficultyLevel = input("Please select a difficulty \
level for the  maths quiz:easy, medium or hard:")
...
#history
difficultyLevel = input("Please select a difficulty \
level for the  history quiz:easy, medium or hard:")
...
```

*3.user answer questions / recode score*

```
#maths
if difficultyLevel == "Easy" or difficultyLevel == "easy": 
    for x in range(0,3):
        print(questionsForMaths[x].rstrip()) 
    userAnswer = input("Choose from the following:").lower()
    if userAnswer == questionsForMaths[1].rstrip():
        print ("correct")
        score = score + 1 
    else:
        print ("incorrect")
    ....
    (other 4 questions)
 ...
 (other difficulty level)

#history
if difficultyLevel == "Easy" or difficultyLevel == "easy":
   for y in range(0,3):
       print(questionsForHistory[y].rstrip()) 
   userAnswer2 = input("Choose from the following:")
   if userAnswer2 == questionsForHistory[2].rstrip():
       print("correct")
       score = score + 1
   else:
       print("incorrect")
   ....
   (other 4 questions)
...
(other difficulty level)
```

*4.show result*

```
print("Your total score is", score)
percentage = (score/5)*100
print("The percentage of questions correct is", percentage)
if percentage < 40.0:
...
```

Thus we can first split it to four functions

```
def open_file(filename):
...
def choose_difficult_level():
...
def answer_questions(topic,difficultyLevel):
...
def show_result(topic, score,fullUsername):
...
```

**open file**

I rewrote your open file code

Yours

```
with open(filename,"r") as topic:
    questionsForMaths/history = topic.readlines()
```

To

```
questions = open(questions_filename).readlines()
```

Just need one-line code, but yours also good, you can keep yours

**choose difficult level**

Also one-line code

```
def choose_difficult_level(topic):
    difficultyLevel = input("Please select a difficulty \
    level for the {} quiz:easy, medium or hard:".format(topic))
    return difficultyLevel
```

Here I use `format`, it is better coding style in python, you can find and read doctumentary about it.

**answer questions**

Let's make this part easier

Basic structor like this

```
def answer_quesions(topic,difficultyLevel):
      #get questions for differnet topic
      score = 0
      if difficultyLevel == "Easy" or difficultyLevel == "easy": 
          ...
          (do easy questions and record score)
      elif difficultyLevel == "Medium" or difficultyLevel == "medium": 
          ...
          (do medium questions and record score)
      elif difficultyLevel == "Hard" or difficultyLevel == "hard":
          ...
          (do hard questions and record score)
      return score
```

It is ok, if it is better for you to understand, just use

```
if toptic == "maths":
    (do maths questions)
elif topic == "history":
    (do history questions)
```

Compare to just code in this function(and make this function super long), it is butter to define functions for different level and different topic

So you can define functions just like this

```
def math_easy_questions():
def history_easy_questions():
```

and call then in your `answer_quesions`

But I still recommend you try to understand my code, the `expectedAnswers` and `level2questions` part

**show result**

Here we can do two things

*1.replace all 'maths' and 'history' to 'topic'*

*2.use string to recode all things need to write in file, then write the string in file(just write in file once)*

```
def show_result(topic, score,fullUsername):
    print("Your total score is", score)
    percentage = (score/5)*100
    print("The percentage of questions correct is", percentage)
    #Add
    reports=""
    if percentage < 40.0:
        #Change
        #print("You have failed the maths quiz")
        print("You have failed the {} quiz".format(topic))
        #Delete
        #with open("reports.txt","a") as reports:
        #    reports.write("\n" + fullUsername + " " + "achieved a grade of fail" + " " + "in the maths quiz")
        #Add 
        reports += "\n" + fullUsername + " " + "achieved a grade of fail" + " " + "in the " + topic + " quiz"
    ...
    (same for other elif)
    #Delete
    #with open("reports.txt","a") as reports:
    #   reports.write("\n" + fullUsername + " " + "did the maths quiz and" + " " + "achieved a score of" + " " + str(score))
    #   reports.write("\n" + fullUsername + " " + "did the maths quiz and" + " " + "achieved a percentage of" + " " + str(percentage))
    reports += "\n" + fullUsername + " " + "did the " + topic + " quiz and" + " " + "achieved a score of" + " " + str(score);
    reports += "\n" + fullUsername + " " + "did the " + topic + " quiz and" + " " + "achieved a percentage of" + " " + str(percentage)
    write_file("reports.txt", reports)
```

Comment: It's bad practice to open a file and not call `close` on it. The `with` statement should stay.